# Creating dynamic menu using Function constructor in an Angular directive, scope not seen

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an Angular controller with an array and two functions defined:

```
anApp.controller('OneCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
  $scope.edit = function(){
    console.log('edit');
  },
  $scope.delete = function(){
    console.log('delete');
  },
  $scope.menuOptions = [
    {
      label: 'Edit',
      function: 'edit'
    },
    {
      label: 'Delete',
      function: 'delete'
    }
  ]
}]);
```

And the view:

```
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="OneCtrl">
    <div id="menu-container" custom-menu="{{menuOptions}}"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to add to `menu-container` a list of links calling different functions from the controller. I have many controllers with different menu options and some dom manipulations (not included in the example) so I've decided to create the menu list using this attribute directive:

```
anApp.directive('customMenu', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, elem, attr){
        var contextMenuDiv = '<ul id="contextmenu-ul">';
            var menuOptionFn = [];
            JSON.parse(attr.customMenu).forEach(function(option, index){
              menuOptionFn.push(new Function('name', 'console.log("menuOptionFn ");scope.' + option.function+'();'));
              contextMenuDiv += '<li class="contextmenu-item" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation();menuOptionFn[' + index + ']()">' + option.label + '</li>';
            });
            contextMenuDiv += '</ul>';

            menuOptionFn[0]();
      }
    };
});
```

But this gives me this console error: *ReferenceError: scope is not defined*. I don't know why `scope` is not seen in the Function constructor.

Here is the (non)working example: https://codepen.io/neptune01/pen/GQwQQd

Comment: This is a natural consequence of using `eval` (which Function constructor is). Eval is evil.

Comment: @estus what else could I use to dynamically generate functions?

Comment: Generally you shouldn't. Because... eval is evil. Usually it's a sign that there is XY problem that could have a better solution.